# Best way to assign Knockout Model

Tags: knockout.js

I have a following examples:

1st example:

```
var model = function(){
 return {
    FirstName: ko.observable(), LastName: ko.observable(), Age: ko.observable()   
  }
}

self.Model = model();

//assumes we get from the server
geCustomer().done(function(json){
   self.Model.FirstName(json.FirstName);
   self.Model.LastName(json.LastName);
   self.Model.Age(json.Age);
});

//then in your html

<input data-bind="text: Model.FirstName" />
<input data-bind="text: Model.LastName" />
<input data-bind="text: Model.Age" />
```

or

in the 2nd Example that i put an observable on the model:

```
   var model = function(){
     return {
        FirstName: '', LastName: '', Age: ''  
      }
    }

    self.Model = ko.observable(model());

    //assumes we get from the server
    geCustomer().done(function(json){
        self.Model(json);
    });

    //then in your html

    <input data-bind="text: Model().FirstName" />
    <input data-bind="text: Model().LastName" />
    <input data-bind="text: Model().Age" />
```

which is better or to follow.
Im not sure the difference or can someone shed light the difference.

Comment: Probably you wanted to use `value` binding for `input`s. `text` binding does not make sense for `input`s.

Comment: its just an example, im more concerned about how do the model accept the value

Answer (score 1):

In example 2 only a change to the entire model will trigger updates. The individual properties on your model are not observable, and changes to them will not propagate to your UI.

This will trigger an update - `self.Model({...new data...})`

This will *not* trigger an update - `self.Model().FirstName = ...new data...;`

So if you plan to update a property by itself either through code or through a UI binding that allows a user to modify it, that change will not be noticed unless that specific property is an observable (like in example 1).

EDIT:
Here's a snippet to show what I mean. The simulated server update functions as you'd expect because it's updating the entire model object, but if you try to type into the input boxes which are tied to individual properties you'll see that the model properties are not updated with what you type.

```js
var model = function() {
  return {
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    Age: ''
  }
}

var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Model = ko.observable(model());

  //assumes we get from the server
  setTimeout(function(json) {
    self.Model({
      FirstName: 'firstname',
      LastName: 'lastname',
      Age: 'age'
    });
  }, 1000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: Model().FirstName" />
<br/>
<input data-bind="textInput: Model().LastName" />
<br/>
<input data-bind="textInput: Model().Age" />
<br/>
<br/> 
FirstName: <span data-bind="text: Model().FirstName"></span>
<br/> 
LastName: <span data-bind=" text: Model().LastName"></span>
<br/> 
Age: <span data-bind="text: Model().Age"></span>
```

Comment: actually the object in example 1 is observable

Comment: @JedMonsanto I never said it wasn't. My answer is primarily explaining the drawbacks of example 2.

Comment: it will still holds a value since the model itself is an observable. i dont need to assign it back as what your example 2 shows.

Comment: its just a simple retrieving data from the server.

Comment: the reason why i made the number 2 because i no longer type every property from json, how about i have 20 properties, then that's the reason why got that solution.

Comment: @JedMonsanto If you have that many properties you might want to look into the mapping plugin which will automatically make every property observable for you. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have two-way data binding using KnockoutJS, then you should use `ko.observable` for the properties for which you want two-way data binding e.g. firstName, lastName and age.

Let's create a model for a customer:

```
var Customer = function(){
  this.firstName = ko.observable();
  this.lastName = ko.observable();
  this.age = ko.observable();
};
```

Next, I've created another object literal to handle server calls as shown below:

```
var CustomerService = {
  getCustomers: function(){
    return [];
  },
  getCustomerById: function(id){
    // fetch customer from somewhere by id...
    var customer = new Customer();
    customer.firstName('sid ' + id);
    customer.lastName('pandey ' + id);
    customer.age(25 + id);

    return customer;
  }  
};
```

Now, both of the snippets can be used together to server up a view-model for view:

```
    var viewModel = {
        customers: CustomerService.getCustomers(),
        selectedCustomer: ko.observable(CustomerService.getCustomerById(1)),
        changeCustomer: function(){
           viewModel.selectedCustomer(CustomerService.getCustomerById(2));
        }
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML looks like this:

```
 <div>
      <input data-bind="value: selectedCustomer().firstName" />
      <input data-bind="value: selectedCustomer().lastName" />
      <input data-bind="value: selectedCustomer().age" />
    </div>

<button data-bind="click: changeCustomer">Change Customer</button>
```

Run this demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/axtkp8v9/3/

Comment: @JedMonsanto if you are using mapping plugin, then let me know and I can add plugin way of updating your view model.

Comment: @JedMonsanto I've updated my answer to show how view will be updated when you get a new customer.